# Cut fields in every second line and join the result to a string with no spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've the following data:

```
cat received.cap | grep -E "0x00(2|3)0" | cut -d " " -f 2-
 0000 0000 bbc0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
 5155 4642 5155 4a43 516b 4a44
 0000 0000 d4da 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
 5130 4e44 5245 5245 5245 5646
 0000 0000 f5f3 0000 0000 0000 0000 0002
 5255 5647 526b 5a47 5230 634b
```

I want the last two fields in every second line:

```
0000 0000
5155 4642 5155 4a43 516b 4a44
0000 0001
5130 4e44 5245 5245 5245 5646
0000 0002
5255 5647 526b 5a47 5230 634b
```

... and join the overall result into a string with no spaces:

```
000000005155464251554a43516b4a440000000151304e445245524552455646...
```

is this possible by continuing my current pipeline?

Comment: [oliv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50619842/5291015) is superior in context as it does everything in `awk` in one-shot. A way to do with some bash-isms involved would be to first get the content as needed into an array using `mapfile` and print it with array expansion removing spaces as `mapfile -t arr < <(awk 'NR%2==1{print $NF,$(NF-1); next}1' file);(IFS=; echo "${arr[*]// /}")` The `IFS` modification and array printing is done in the sub-shell, so need to use `()` to not make the change to the parent shell. [ Moved it to comment as it could be slower than other voted answers ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append

```
| sed 'N;s/\n//' | cut -d " " -f 1-2,9- | tr -d ' \n'
```

or

```
| awk '{all=all $1 $2; getline; all=all $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6} END{print all}'
```

Output:

```
000000005155464251554a43516b4a440000000151304e4452455245524556460000000252555647526b5a475230634b
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided your input file is:

```
$ cat file 
 0000 0000 bbc0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
 5155 4642 5155 4a43 516b 4a44
 0000 0000 d4da 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
 5130 4e44 5245 5245 5245 5646
 0000 0000 f5f3 0000 0000 0000 0000 0002
 5255 5647 526b 5a47 5230 634b
```

You could use this `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR%2{print $(NF-1),$NF} (NR+1)%2{$1=$1;print}' OFS="" ORS="" file
```

This relies on `NR` which represents the number of record (e.g. line). It prints for *every second line* the last 2 fields.

`OFS` and `ORS` are output delimiters set to empty string to get everything in one line without space.

The statement `$1=$1` is to force awk to reformat the string according to the format imposed by `ORS` and `OFS`.

If you want a newline at the end of the string, you can add the statement `END{print "\n"}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use sed with the `~` address to replace every second line, than `tr` to remove whitespace:

```
... | sed '1~2s/.*\( [^ ]* [^ ]*$\)/\1/' | tr -d ' \n'
```

You can probably use sed for the previous steps, too, to make it faster, but since you haven't posted the original input, I can't experiment with it.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may also help you here.

```
awk '
NR%2!=0{
  val=val?val $(NF-1) $NF:$(NF-1) $NF;
  next}
{
  gsub(/ /,"" );
  val=val?val $0:$0
}
END{
  print val
}'  Input_file
```

Or if you want to append it to your previous command then do `your_command(s) | awk command above...` too.